# Can not pass bitmap from activity to AIDL service

Tags: android

I am trying to pass a bitmap which is created from DrawingCache (in my activity class) to the AIDL service. But that doesn't get passed to the Service. Even the storeImage method in my service doesn't prints my logs. Though if I take any bitmap (png) from the resources and then pass it from my activity to the AIDL service, it works.

Due to some restriction I can not add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to my activity class, that is why I am passing this bitmap to service to store it in Sdcard. If temporarily I add this permission to my activity, and do storing process in activity class only then the image is properly stored. But if I put this image in resource folder and then send it over to the AIDL service, storeImage method is not called.

This code works on most of the devices but few of them doesn't work. Is this the bitmap created using view.getDrawingCache() is wrong?

Here is the code block:

```
 view.buildDrawingCache();
 bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();

 //This code block sends the bitmap to the service

if (logProvider != null && logProvider.isServiceRunning()) {
    logProvider.storeBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sort of mediator class since you can only communicate to your service from elsewhere in the app (such as Activities) by native data types.  If you create a class with a static HashMap, you can store the Bitmap and some kind of key (maybe the timestamp of when this is being stored or some other way of distinguishing the Bitmap) and then pass the key to the Service, the Service can then retrieve the Bitmap using the key.  Make sure to clean up the Bitmap reference when you're done and on failure.

Comment: Scaling the bitmap did the trick. I think it was the size of the bitmap. Hence for my case I can conclude that sending a bitmap to the remote service has some size restriction. Now code is working on Samsung tablet too. Here is how I did: bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, true);

Comment: If you're doing IPC there are some size restrictions indeed. Also it can be somewhat slow and it might be a good idea to transfer, say, png compressed image instead. And to make sure you do not hit IPC size limits you can always send image data in chunks.